# How to obfuscate and pack a whole project with pyarmor?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyarmor

I was planning to obfuscate and create a executable file for my project. The problem is when I pack, the "rsc" folder are not included in the packed project but just the Spring.py.

Can anyone help me ?
Best regards,

[image]

Comment: Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `pack` argument, and include --add-data to include your folder

`pyarmor pack -e " --onefile --icon=logo.ico --add-data path/to/dir;dest/dir" Spring.py`

Answer (score 0):

Hi from what I understand you can obfuscate your scripts first then use pyinstaller normally selecting the obfuscated files and it will create your executable.